# Chromedriver fails when runs from Jenkins or linux console

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with the last chromedriver. Fails every time with the following error:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615279
> (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5) on port 2393 Only local
> connections are allowed. org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

The browser version is

> Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

When I run from eclipse everything works OK, does not fail. Fails only when I run from Jenkins or Linux console. The chromedriver process remains hanged on Linux. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `--no-sandbox` flag:

```
ChromeOptions ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "window-size=1024,768", "--no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);
```

Or, some were helped by `--single-process` option, as suggested [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961).

Answer (score 0):

The fix is hidden in the answer above. For me, the only option that was needed to fix this issue was to run chrome in a headless mode.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Results: Now tests run successfully, without any errors.